# Lots of vandalism by anonymous edit suggestions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, anonymous, vandalism

I often see vandalism while reviewing edit suggestions. Most of these are submitted by anonymous users. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/327091)

Is there a way for moderators to block these users? And do we really need anonymous edit suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. There are only a few every day. I'm more worried about subtly bad edits made by user with account being approved.

Comment: Isn't this why we have the review process in the first place? I would only consider stopping suggested edits from anonymous users if there are actual figures telling me that their suggestions end up being rejected a disproportionate amount of times.

Comment: @Bart, I have kept no stats, but I see >50% vandalism lately.

Comment: Okay, if that's truly the case then it might be worth considering.

Comment: @Bart: From my experience, there are some good anon edits, but it pales in comparison to bad anon edits. (However, the point I made above is that anon edits are not that frequent anyway).

Comment: @nhahtdh I review quite a lot as well and had a similar "feeling" but assumed it was me remembering the bad ones more than the good ones. That's why I'd like to see figures.

Comment: You can check out the anonymous edits at: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=month&tab=anonymous - 998 this month, most seem to have been approved but a lot seem to be controversial (3 reviewers). Weirdly that's quite a different picture to: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60664/breakdown-of-anonymously-suggested-edits

Comment: i'm still laughing at the suggested edit you gave as example:)

Comment: @Flexo - When I do a quick count, there were 91 approved edits out of 244 for anonymous over the last week, for a 37% approval rate. The data.stackexchange.com query shows a 36% approval rate, so that seems to be a pretty good match to me. Those are not very good numbers.

Comment: @BradLarson - it's not great but it's also not awful and as a percentage of the total submitted edits it's quite low (~3%) so blocking them wouldn't do much to keep the edit queue in shape. (However it settles after recent changes)

Comment: @Flexo - Yeah, and I've seen plenty more spam edits and attempted comments from named users than anonymous in my own experience.